# Hidden Spinner does not trigger event

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-event

I have a spinner in an Activity, the spinner is hidden initially, but when I load the items into it I initially set the selected item to the index 1, like this:

```
spinner.setSelection(1);
```

This triggers the item selected listener only if the spinner is not hidden, but if I hide it (I need to hide it initially to show a progressbar while I load some data) then the listener is not called.

Is there a way I can force the event to dispatch?

Comment: how do you hide it sir? `View.GONE` ?

Comment: yes, but on the parent

Comment: okay why don't you try `View.INVISIBLE` or `alpha` to 0.. it will take screen space, and regarded, but transparent

Comment: Yes, that worked. thanks, you should post the answer so I accept it

Comment: a little upvote would be pretty nice though? ):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change visibility from `View.GONE` to `View.INVISIBLE`- *invisible takes Screen space,which means android takes it into account but its just not visible to the user* **or** set `alpha` on your `View` or `ViewGroup`